# Rectangle positioning is getting overridden

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to position text to be centered, and at a certain distance from the top of the web page.
The problem occurring is that setting the position to absolute overrides the `text-align: centered;` command.
I also am not able to relocate the text upwards.
Why is this happening?

```
h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:impact;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant HTML? Also, you may need to set an explicit width on your h1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your h1 position to absolute makes the h1 element take it's parent's relative position. Text-align will set the text to the center of it's parents relative position.  So they are contradicting each other and absolute positioning will always win.

It's a bad idea to have an h1 tag take an absolute position. I would instead create a parent div for the h1 element to take the absolute position. Check out this jsfiddle as an example. Also, play around with the various ways absolute positioning effects the different elements.

```
    <div id="test">
       <div id="abs">
          <p class="text"> Hello </p>
       </div>
     </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexflores67/wb1dh7h9/2/#&togetherjs=C1mAFQldMN

Good luck!